# Find the best 3 number combinations from a set of numbers whose sums are close

Tags: combinatorics

Lets say I have the following set of numbers:

{31.5, 32.9, 39.5, 39.5, 56.2, 56.5, 57.5, 76, 76, 76, 76, 77, 78, 78.5, 87.9, 95.2, 97.5, 103}

...and I'm looking for the best 3 number combinations (no re-use, there will always be 18 numbers in the set).

Manually doing it, by using sums (not necessarily the ideal outcome, just what I have currently), I have come up with:

{95.2, 77, 76} = 248.2

{56.5, 103, 76} = 235.5

{76, 76, 78} = 230

{87.9, 78.5, 56.2} = 222.6

{31.5, 32.9, 97.5} = 161.9

{39.5, 39.5, 57.5} = 136.5

End desire is to be able to pass the set of numbers into PHP and present the results/combinations (not the ask) but don't know where to start. What would the "method" in Mathematics be for this type of determination?

Thank you very much =)

**Edit 1:** Best where in the sums of the numbers are as close together as possible.

**Edit 2:** I've shown the sums.

**Edit 3:** Clarified the subject/title.

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?

Comment: Best where in the sums of the numbers are as close together as possible. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Which sums? Can you give an example calculation for whether one set of three numbers is better than another?

Comment: @Karl I've edited the manual set to show the sums. The ideal outcome is to have 6 sets of three numbers whose sums are as close together as possible.

Comment: I see. Do you define "best" in terms of (say) the variance in the set of sums, or e.g. the difference between the largest and smallest sums, or something else?

Comment: I'm looking for best, even, distribution so that the sum of each resultant set is minimally deviant from the others (so *not* best -> worst)

Comment: @ironchefbadass, did you see my answer below?

Comment: Partitionning a set of 18 numbers in 6 group of 3 numbers, such that standard-deviation of the 6 sums is minimal. "Partitionning" is probably the key-word that was missing, so nobody could understand your objective.

Comment: @Doug I did, thank you! I'll need to sit down and knock some code out to see how my feeble attempt plays out =D

Comment: @Lourrran you got it. I'm not great on Mathematical terminology.

Comment: The search space is small enough to use a brute force approach. The best partitioning of this dataset has sums $\{200.0,205.9,206.0,206.1,208.2,208.5\}$. @Doug's algorithm is sufficient, but rather than random subsets, test all three-element subsets containing the smallest available element at each level of recursion.

Comment: @DanielMathias I'm not sure how that's possible unless there is number re-use. A value can only be used once in a subset.

Comment: Your example includes the subset $\{76,76,78\}$, and the partition I found has subsets $\{56.2,76,76\}$ and $\{56.5,76,76\}$, all of which are (or should be) valid because of the repetition in the dataset.

Comment: Are you able to share how you came to the six partitions?

Comment: I used a recursive algorithm, similar to what Doug described, that is able to check all 190 million possible partitions. With a tolerance of $5\%$ of the average, the code only checks about 41,000 full partitions.

Comment: @DanielMathias are you able to share your work in a posted answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of playing, this seems to give me the best results:

```
<?php
// Input array of numbers
$numbers = [31.5, 33.9, 39.5, 39.5, 56.5, 57.3, 60, 76, 76, 77, 78, 79.5, 79.5, 79.5, 94, 95.3, 98.6, 103.1];

// Sort the numbers in descending order
rsort($numbers);

// Initialize an array to hold the subsets
$subsets = [[], [], [], [], [], []];

// Distribute the numbers into the subsets
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $minSum = PHP_INT_MAX;
    $minIndex = -1;
    // Find the subset with the smallest sum
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($subsets); $i++) {
        $sum = array_sum($subsets[$i]);
        if (count($subsets[$i]) < 3 && $sum < $minSum) {
            $minSum = $sum;
            $minIndex = $i;
        }
    }
    // Add the number to the selected subset
    array_push($subsets[$minIndex], $number);
}

// Print the subsets
foreach ($subsets as $subset) {
    echo 'Subset: '.implode(", ", $subset) . " | Sum: ".array_sum($subset)."\n";
}
```

Yielding:

```
Subset: 103.1, 60, 39.5 | Sum: 202.6
Subset: 98.6, 76, 31.5 | Sum: 206.1
Subset: 95.3, 76, 33.9 | Sum: 205.2
Subset: 94, 77, 39.5 | Sum: 210.5
Subset: 79.5, 79.5, 56.5 | Sum: 215.5
Subset: 79.5, 78, 57.3 | Sum: 214.8
```

I guess the better way to have asked this question was, how to evenly distribute the set into six subsets of three unique numbers.

Answer (score 0):

So we have 3n numbers. To simplify things we calculate the average of the numbers and subtract it from each number. Now the sum of the numbers is zero. The average of the n sums of three numbers is also zero. The problem is now a bit simpler: Split into n groups of three, for each group square the sum of the three elements, sum the squares, and minimise.

Let's say we decided on k groups with a total of s. Then we have n-k groups with a total of -s left. The best, if this was possible, would be to split the remaining groups into n-k groups with sum -s/(n-k) each, the sum squared will be $s^2 / (n-k)^2$ for each group, and the sum of squared sums is $s^2 / (n-k)$.

To get a reasonably good sum, we repeat n times: Pick the smallest and the largest of the remaining numbers, then add another one that makes the sum of 3 as close to -s/(n-k) as possible. We calculate the sum of variances for each of those and try to find something better.

Now we try to find the first group of three: We pick the smallest of the numbers, then we pick any combination of two more numbers, and for each combination we calculate the lower bound for the variance if we manage to split the remaining numbers optimal. If this is worse than the one solution that we had then we reject it. Otherwise we pick the second, third group and so on.

So for any three numbers a, b, c, we define sq(a, b, c) = (a + b + c)^2. After picking the first k groups with a sum of elements = s, and the sum of sq(a, b, c) = ssq, the lower bound for the sum of squares of the remaining numbers is $s^2 / (n-k)$, and the lower bound for the total sum of squares is $ssq + s^2 / (n-k)$. We start with k = 0, s = 0, ssq = 0. Then we pick three numbers a, b, c for the first group: The smallest one is a, plus two others, b and c, update $s \leftarrow s + (a + b + c)$, $ssq \leftarrow ssq + (a + b + c)^2$, calculate the lower bound for the optimal ssq which is $ssq + s^2 / (n-k)$, and check that it is not too large.

It's quite hard to estimate how many solutions we may be able to throw out. In the worst case, we have $(2n!) / 2^n$ sets to try, but hopefully many cases will be thrown out. It may be less effort if we first find all choices for the set of three, sort them in increasing order of the lower bound, and try them in that order, hoping that we find a good solution quicker which allows us to throw out more bad ones.

Comment: This is an amazingly thorough and well presented response however I'm simply not mathematically sound to know how to proceed further without a perhaps a example, if even based on a smaller source set of numbers? Thank you very much =)